# Sum group of values XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have created a group of values using the `for-each-group` functionality, however I have now been left with a group of values which is considered a string:

```
22.22, 20.00, 31.00, 12.58
```

I am now trying to sum this group of values using the following statement:

```
format-number(sum(current-group()/total),'0.00')
```

However I am receiving the following error:

```
Description: Cannot convert string to double: ""
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction!

Comment: Please show us the relevant context, like the relevant XML snippet and the template in the XSLT so that we can see which elements you group.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why would grouping leave you with a string of concatenated values? Please show us an example of the input and how you do the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

If you have XPath 3.1 available, then you can use:

```
sum(for-each(tokenize(current-group(), ", "),xs:double#1))
```

to calculate the sum of `85.8`.

Your life would be easier if you had something like

```
<number>22.22</number>
<number>20.00</number>
<number>31.00</number>
<number>12.58</number>
```

Then you could sum the numbers up by simply calling

```
sum(//number)
```

which is available even in XPath 1.0.